# Can the word `task` on its own be used to refer to a physical place (e.g. short for `task surface`)?

Tags: word-usage, terminology

In a paper about [Photo-Electrically Controlled Lighting Systems by Francis Rubinstein et. al.](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/7080873) (a native English speaker as far as I know) I've come across some wording that seems incorrect to me. The word `task` is used multiple times in a context where at other times `task surface` is used.

#### Examples for the usage of `task surface` in 3 different places in the paper:

> The ability of a photo-electrically controlled lighting system to
>   maintain a constant total light level on a **task surface** by
>   responding to changing day light levels (...)
>   ..
>   The first constraint is particularly important because the control
>   objective is expressed in terms of the illuminance at the **task
>   surface** (or work plane).
>   ..
>   (...) the control photo sensor is generally mounted in the ceiling
>   rather than at the **task surface**, (...)

#### Examples fo the usage of `task` in 5 different places in the paper:

> We describe the major components (...), and derive expressions for each
>   algorithm that express the total illuminance at the **task** as a function
>   of the control photo sensor signal.
>   ..
>   We then use experimental data from scale models to demonstrate how the
>   control algorithm and the photo sensor's geometry and location affect
>   the ability of photo-electrically lighting systems to provide a
>   specified illuminance level at the **task**.
>   ..
>   Although placing the photo sensor at the **task** would be ideal from
>   an operational standpoint (...)
>   ..
>   For example, a ceiling-mounted photo sensor doesn't directly measure
>   the illuminance at the **task**.
>   ..
>   By expressing each algorithm mathematically, we can derive expressions
>   for the total light level at the **task** as a function of the
>   daylight component of the photosensor signal and daylight on the
>   **task** for each algorithm.

I think `task surface` should be used instead of `task` in the examples above. At least that's how I understand it. Using the word `task` on its own in those cases sounds incorrect to me but I'm no native speaker.
Is the usage of `task` on its own correct in the 5 examples above and if yes why? Can the word `task` on its own be used as a reference to a physical place?

It just seems odd to me when one speaks of a `task` having a light level or illuminance or placing a sensor at a `task`.

Comment: The use of the word "task" here seems to be a piece of cant or jargon. I can't understand the use of the word "task" in either section.

Comment: This is technical English. The task surface means: the surface on which the task is performed. And it's obviously written by a native speaker. At the task means: at the place of the object on which the task is being performed.

Answer (score 1):

Nouns can be used [attributatively](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-noun-1689012).  From that link:

> In English grammar, an attributive noun is a noun that modifies
>   another noun and functions as an adjective. Also known as a noun
>   premodifier, a noun adjunct, and a converted adjective.

*Task surface* is the noun *task* being used in this way.

If you don't use *task* with another word like you would use an adjective, then it will no longer be attributive.  So you can't do this:

> I've cleaned my task surface, and now I'm going to put some things on my task.

In your second paragraph ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=P8Zn8p8ZrZUC&pg=PA218&lpg=PA218&dq=We%20describe%20the%20major%20components%20(...),%20and%20derive%20expressions%20for%20each%20algorithm%20that%20express%20the%20total%20illuminance%20at%20the%20task%20as%20a%20function%20of%20the%20control%20photo%20sensor%20signal.&source=bl&ots=NiwwsOLeBC&sig=ACfU3U0WMquwPPPhjOoBelKhfbnaB4aXCA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi7-cWw3urlAhUDnKwKHT-ZAswQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=task&f=false)), I think there's an error in the text and the word *surface* was accidentally omitted.

Comment: I also first thought that using `task` on its own was an accidental error but it's not only used in one paragraph but in multiple paragraphs across the paper and also in a different paper by the same author team. So from your answer and the comments I take that using `task` on its own as a short term for `task surface` or `task area` would be incorrect in common English but considering the frequency with which `task` (on its own) is used and the fact that the authors are native English speakers I guess it's acceptable lingo in a scientific paper or the author just has a strange diction.